# difference between two times in am/pm format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want find the difference between two time in the format of AP/PM in jquery.

i had tested many codes but can't find any solution.

One of my code is here.

```
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "05.00 AM").getHours();
var timeStartmin = new Date("01/01/2007 "  + "05.00 AM").getMinutes();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "10.30 PM").getHours();
var timeEndmin = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "10.30 PM").getMinutes();

timeStart     =   timeStart+"."+timeStartmin;
timeEnd     =   timeEnd+"."+timeEndmin;

var hourDiff = timeEnd-timeStart;    
alert(hourDiff);
```

but it doesn't works properly. Can any body give me an advise.

Comment: whats in `valuestop`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You initialize your dates incorrectly. This is how you should do it:

```
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "05:00 AM");
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "10:30 PM");

var diff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 60000; //dividing by seconds and milliseconds

var minutes = diff % 60;
var hours = (diff - minutes) / 60;
```

Then you can do with `hours` and `minutes` whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

first of all `Date()` will not accept `"01/01/2007 " + "05.00 PM"` it will return NaN on getHours() and on other also.so you need to pass

```
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "05:00:00").getHours();
```

and do this:

```
var diffhour     =   parseInt(timeEnd)-parseInt(timeStart);
var diffmin     =   parseInt(timeStartmin)-parseInt(timeEndmin);

var Diff = diffhour+":"+diffmin;    
alert(Diff);
```

Comment: what is the solution ?

Comment: what should i tell even timeStart,timeEnd itselt will be NaN.