# Dropdown fromtime select previous time disable in totime

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, dropdown

I have 2 select box `from time` and `to time`.

If am select `1.00 AM` in from time, `12.00 AM` and `12.30 AM` option disable in `to time`.

I tired some code but i am not get correct result.

```js
$('#fromtime').on('change', function(){
    var totimeValues = [];
    
    var fromTime = $(this).val();

    $('#totime option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() <= fromTime;
    }).prop('disabled', true);

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="fromtime">From Time</label>
          <select  class="form-control" id="fromtime" (change)="changeFromTime($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">Select from time</option>
              <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
              <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
              <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
              <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
              <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
              <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
              <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
              <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
              <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
              <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
              <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
              <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
              <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
              <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
              <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
              <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
              <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
              <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
              <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
              <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
              <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
              <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
              <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
              <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
              <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
              <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
              <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
              <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
              <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
              <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
              <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
              <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
              <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
              <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
              <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
              <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
              <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
              <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
              <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
              <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
              <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
              <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
              <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
              <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
              <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
              <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
              <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="totime">To Time:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="totime">
            <option value="">Select to time</option>
              <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
              <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
              <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
              <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
              <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
              <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
              <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
              <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
              <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
              <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
              <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
              <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
              <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
              <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
              <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
              <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
              <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
              <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
              <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
              <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
              <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
              <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
              <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
              <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
              <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
              <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
              <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
              <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
              <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
              <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
              <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
              <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
              <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
              <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
              <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
              <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
              <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
              <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
              <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
              <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
              <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
              <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
              <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
              <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
              <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
              <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
              <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
              <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
            </select>
      </div>
```

> If am select `1.00 AM` in `from time` my code disable `10.00 PM`, `10.30 PM`,`11.00 PM`, and `11.30 PM` in `to time`. But i need to disable only `12.00 AM` and `12.30 AM`

Comment: what is the issue ? how do you want it to be functioning ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two times in am/pm format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561809/difference-between-two-times-in-am-pm-format-in-javascript)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: If am select `1.00 AM` my code disable `10.00 PM`, `10.30 PM`,`11.00 PM`, and `11.30 PM`. But i need to disable only `12.00 AM` and `12.30 AM`

Comment: @Eddie: Am not using `PHP`

Comment: That's on javascript. You can convert the string to time first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a date with the time as select in `fromTime` and then do that same for each option in `totime` and then you can compare the dates and that should work.

Check here

```js
$('#fromtime').on('change', function(){
    
    
    var fromTime = $(this).val();
    
  
    var today = new Date("11/24/1993 " + $(this).val());
     
  
    $('#totime option').filter(function() {
      
      var tempDate = new Date("11/24/1993 "+$(this).val());
        return tempDate <= today;
    }).prop('disabled', true);

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="fromtime">From Time</label>
          <select  class="form-control" id="fromtime" (change)="changeFromTime($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">Select from time</option>
              <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
              <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
              <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
              <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
              <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
              <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
              <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
              <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
              <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
              <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
              <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
              <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
              <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
              <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
              <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
              <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
              <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
              <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
              <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
              <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
              <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
              <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
              <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
              <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
              <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
              <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
              <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
              <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
              <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
              <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
              <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
              <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
              <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
              <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
              <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
              <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
              <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
              <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
              <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
              <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
              <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
              <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
              <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
              <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
              <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
              <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
              <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="totime">To Time:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="totime">
            <option value="">Select to time</option>
              <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
              <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
              <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
              <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
              <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
              <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
              <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
              <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
              <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
              <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
              <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
              <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
              <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
              <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
              <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
              <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
              <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
              <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
              <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
              <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
              <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
              <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
              <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
              <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
              <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
              <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
              <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
              <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
              <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
              <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
              <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
              <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
              <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
              <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
              <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
              <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
              <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
              <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
              <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
              <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
              <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
              <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
              <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
              <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
              <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
              <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
              <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
              <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
            </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its working. `11/24/1993` is your dob ? ;)

Comment: Haha. No it's not :p

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake: compare between two string not time type

```
$('#totime option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() <= fromTime; //compare strings
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

You can this trick to compare time type. Change format option's value

```
<option value="AM 00:00">12:00 AM</option>
<option value="AM 00:30">12:30 AM</option>
<option value="AM 01:00">01:00 AM</option>
<option value="AM 01:30">01:30 AM</option>
...
<option value="PM 00:00">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="PM 00:30">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="PM 01:00">01:00 PM</option>
<option value="PM 01:30">01:30 PM</option>
```

or use mommentjs. Note: option's value must is format hh:mm A

```
function compare(dateTimeA, dateTimeB) {
   var momentA = moment(dateTimeA,"hh:mm A");
   var momentB = moment(dateTimeB,"hh:mm A");
   if (momentA <= momentB) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

then

```
....
$('#totime option').filter(function() {
    return compare($(this).val(), fromTime);
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer